# Property 'getLayout' does not exist in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working with Reactjs and using Nextjs,Right now i am trying to "Use multiple Headers" (according to condition) , I used following code in my "about.js" file

```
import React from 'react'
import NestedLayout from '../components/NestedLayout'
import Footer from '../components/Footer'

function About() {
  return (
    <>
 <>
    //CODE HERE
 </>
  </>
  )
}
export default About
About.getLayout= function PageLayout(page)
{
    return(
        <>
            <NestedLayout />
            {page}
            <Footer />
        </>
    )
}
```

And here is my "_app.js" file

```
import React from 'react';
import App from 'next/app';
import Layout from '../components/layout'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  
  if(Component.getLayout)
  {
      return Component.getLayout(<Component{...pageProps} />)
  }
  return (
    <>
     <Layout>
     <Component {...pageProps} />
     </Layout>
    </>
   )
}
export default MyApp
```

But i am getting following error,How can  i solve this ?

```
any
Property 'getLayout' does not exist on type 'NextComponentType<NextPageContext, any, {}>'.
  Property 'getLayout' does not exist on type 'ComponentClass<{}, any> & { getInitialProps?(context: NextPageContext): any; }'.ts(2339)
```

Comment: Have a look at [this article](https://dev.to/ofilipowicz/next-js-per-page-layouts-and-typescript-lh5) for a suggested fix for this

Comment: You should extend the `NextPage` type to include the `getLayout` property. See [Type error when assigning extended NextPage type to a page component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73002071/type-error-when-assigning-extended-nextpage-type-to-a-page-component).